# Python multiple inheritence issues

Tags: python, multiple-inheritance, tornado, mixins

I'm trying to run python code that has an inheritence pattern like so:

```
A Object
|   /\
|  B C
|  | |
|  D E
 \ | /
  \|/
   F
A = Base Handler
B = OAuth2 Mixin
C = OAuth Mixin
D = Facebook Graph Mixin
E = Twitter Mixin
```

The function names in B, C, D, E overlap. D and E are mixins so they shouldn't be independently spawned. How can I resolve this so class F can make calls to specific mixins?

Comment: If you need to call a function's implementation in B, even though E indirectly extends from it, there's something awfully wrong with your code somewhere.  Are you really meant to be extending them, instead of using agregation?

Comment: how would I aggregate into a single class? Does this use import or something?
P.S. I don't need to call the version in B, I only need to call the version in C and D, which go by the same name.

Comment: Then have an instance of C and D inside your class E (as attributes) instead of extending from those.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know the names of `C` and `D` ahead of time, you can just call their methods and pass `self` explicitly:

```
class E(C, D):
    def do_c_thing(self):
        # Call C's version
        C.some_method(self, ...)

    def do_d_thing(self):
        # Call D's version
        D.some_method(self, ...)
```

Comment: When I try and do this it still calls C's copy.

(I can tell because when I toggle the order in the class def half the code starts working, and the other half stops)

Comment: Are you sure? Keep in mind that a lot of Tornado code is callback-based, and thus if anything within D's copy does something like `add_callback(self.foo)`, that'll add a copy of whatever `foo` resolves to on your object, even if it was `D`'s copy that was called initially. If what you're calling utilizes callbacks, you may need to not inherit but instead just create child objects and call things on them.

Comment: I think that must be it. I didn't realize that a callback in D would check E's MRO. The only issue is that technically B, C, and D are Mixins so they shouldn't be spawned as objects. (I'm doing oauth, C and D are facebook/twitter, B is Oauth2)

Comment: What is A? OAuth2 seems like something that is self-sufficient.

Comment: A is a Base Web request handler with definitions of current facebook and twitter user.

Comment: Ah - I messed up in my initial analysis. I've updated the question above.

Comment: Given your update, I'd recommend creating separate handlers for each. Make a handler that is your Twitter auth endpoint, and another handler that is your Facebook auth endpoint. Don't try to map them both onto the same handler; it's just asking for trouble.

Comment: Yeah, that works, it just isn't as pretty :). But if that's the way to do it, thats the way to do it. Thanks for all the help!

Answer (score 1):

Reconsider whether inheriting from both is *really* what you want to do. If you only inherit from A and C, and just keep an instance of D around, like so:

```
class E(A, C):
   def __init__(self):
      self.d = D()
```

, then `self.foo()` goes up the mro to `B.foo`. To call `D.foo`, you would do `self.d.foo()`. You will also need to explicitly wrap any other methods of `D` that you want in `E` - which if you're using Python 3, is as easy as:

```
def __init__(self):
    self.d = D()
    self.bar = d.bar
```

In Python 2, this won't work, and the easiest way is to write the wrapper like so:

```
def bar(self):
   return self.d.bar()
```